# WordPress Dynamic Contents with Different Header and/or Footer

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, plugins, multilingual

I am finding a solution to create pages of WordPress that have different header and footer contents (texts or picture different).

Supposed that one of my page has a link *domain.com/firstcontent*, I want to create another page with different header and footer contents which could be like *domain.com/secondbranch/firstcontent*.

However, I do not want to duplicate the whole website, because I want to change the header and footer of 'some' pages only.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically for WP pages header and footer are included in page.php..

So if you want to inlcude some different header and footer for specific pages then

```
if(get_the_ID() == 12){
get_header('12');
}
```

> and a header-12.php file should be created in the active theme folder.
>   Same goes for footer

Normally there is get_header() which call header.php